# How do I scrape the starting pitchers and import to excel?

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, lxml

How do I scrape the starting pitchers and import to excel?

Here is my code so far.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml import html

response = urlopen("https://www.baseball-reference.com/previews/index.shtml")
content = response.read()
tree = html.fromstring(content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll get you started. First you want to use cssselect unless you like xpath:

```
import cssselect
```

Then you just figure out the css for the things you want to iterate:

```
for div in tree.cssselect('.game_summaries'):
  for a in div.cssselect('table:nth-child(2) a'):
    print(a.text)
```

You can find the css from the elements inspector of your browser (chrome is best).

Comment: @JakeWest If the answer helped, you can mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark under the vote buttons.

Comment: @pguardiario... Can I remove any of my lines of code?

Comment: No, you're going to need all of them.